# Set an array to select different variables onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, onclick

I have a little experimental setup that I am editing to create a div that appears at random times and when you click it goes away. I am having issues forcing the variable "x" to be a different number from the array everytime you click it. Instead it will pick one number from the array at the start and stick with it the entire time.

DIV:

```
<div id="div" onclick="hide()" style="visibility:hidden;">Doge</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">  

var interval = [5000, 1000, 10000, 6000, 500];
var x = interval[Math.floor(Math.random() * interval.length)];
setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById('div').style.visibility = "visible";
},x);

function hide(){
document.getElementById('div').style.visibility = "hidden";
var x = interval[Math.floor(Math.random() * interval.length)];
}

</script>
```

Every time you click the div I want it to reappear at a different time interval.

Comment: why there is 2 script tag

Comment: @Mahi fixed, shortened it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` takes a `delay` value and uses that for every interval. It is not affected by you updating the variable. What you want is `setTimeout`, which you will set every time that your `hide` function is called.

```
var interval = [5000, 1000, 10000, 6000, 500];
var div = document.getElementById('div');

function hide(){
  div.style.visibility = "hidden";
  showIn(randomInterval());
}

function randomInterval() {
  return interval[Math.floor(Math.random() * interval.length)];
}

function showIn(delay) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    div.style.visibility = "visible";
  }, delay);
}

// call directly in the beginning to show the div
showIn(randomInterval());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your random generation number, most of the times it is repeating the same value again and again.

[Link of your random number generation output](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FA9X5H0JOA1G)

Try to resolve this and try again.

Comment: This does force it to spout a different variable in the array every time, but I am trying to make the time variable 'x' in the 'setinterval' to be a different time everytime.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">  

var interval = [5000, 1000, 10000, 6000, 500];
var x = interval[Math.floor(Math.random() * interval.length)];
setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById('div').style.visibility = "visible";
},x);

function hide(){
document.getElementById('div').style.visibility = "hidden";
var x = interval[Math.floor(Math.random() * interval.length)];
 setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById('div').style.visibility = "visible";
},x);
}

</script>
```

Comment: This is probably because in order to give x in the setinterval a time to go by, it needs to have something predefined. @Mahi

Comment: see my edited if not working then show show us your snippet or fiddle